# Ensure my Iomega NAS storage is working optimally

Tags: nas, diagnostic

We have a NAS storage of 5.5 TB from Iomega which is around 96% full and around 3-4 yrs old. We have started doubting if the performance has degraded a lot of this NAS storage, e.g. IOPS. For example, if we need to find disk usage of all folders, it's taking days to execute.

How can we benchmark this storage, or ensure if this storage has any problem?

Comment: What OS are you using? What specific model of NAS do you have?

Comment: Can you pull the drives out of the NAS and put them in a computer to check their health ?

Comment: @Deepak: Are you using RAID? Your NAS should have pages that list the overall status of the RAID array as well as the SMART status of each disk. Have you checked for any warnings?

Comment: @James: iOmega RX200

Comment: @harrymc No we cant.

Comment: @James: Yes , we are using RAID 5. We are using 4 number of 2 TBs SATA hard disk. That GUI we are not getting now.. Previously we used to see that GUI and know about performance... Not sure if its the problem of this iomega.

Comment: @Deepak: What happens when you try to access the administration interface?

Comment: @James when we try to open the GUI from the browser; nothing shows up and eventually gets timedout. If we do a hard reboot; then GUI starts showing up.

Comment: Cannot find any RX200 on the Iomega/LenovoEMC website.

Comment: @Deepak: Are you saying you cannot access the interface even after rebooting the device? You really need to check the system status pages if possible as I suspect one of your drives is failing and the RAID has degraded. Either way you need to back up what you can because something is clearly wrong.

Comment: @harrymc Storage is Iomega StorCenter Pro NAS ix4-200r. http://download.iomega.com/com/nas/pdfs/vmware_200r_wp.pdf

Comment: @James Yes we can access interface only after rebooting ( power reboot ) the device. Till then nothing comes up on the browser.

Comment: @Deepak: Have you checked the dashboard for errors or warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better verify first that the amount of RAM reported is correct.
You can also test the performance of the NAS to verify if it is within parameters. See:
[7 Free Hard Drive Testing Programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/tophddiag.htm).

However, the only way to really test the drives is to
pull them out of the NAS and put them in a computer to check their health
with non-destructive tests. I have had good results with the old but still wonderful
[SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) (never on 2 TB disks).

One possible action is to update the firmware to
[Version 2.1.42.18967](https://lenovo-eu-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29782) from august 2012,
described as "provides performance improvements".
But ensure first that you have a backup and are capable of reinstalling the current
firmware under all possible conditions (even if the device is bricked).
The device does have a Factory Reset button.

This [Amazon review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2JH6M5D0UE2W3/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B004Z02XX8&linkCode=&nodeID=&tag=) of the PX4-300d points to a problem that might pertain :

> I later found out by looking at a firmware release notes that there's
>   an existing issue that applies to all StorCenter products where "you
>   may experience a decrease in network performance" "if you bond network
>   interface cards (NICs) on your Iomega StorCenter device and are
>   running the device in a gigabit LAN". This information is not
>   published in any of their FAQs or other product documentation.

This might mean that your network is now too fast for the NAS and causes performance
degradation. Maybe the firmware update can fix this.

If nothing works, it may be time to invest in a new NAS.
I remark that most of the reviews on Amazon of Iomega StorCenter
were quite negative,